# Sliding effect for opening menu in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to open a sliding menu when we click on top button. Please check the below image. when i click on red marked image/button then how can i open a sliding menu/list items as you can see in 2nd image.

When this menus gets open then main window get slide toward right side of the screen where small part of the main screen will be visible.

I am not sure if this menu is a list of view!! Please help me out.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best Library doing that is [SlindingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) from jfeinstein10 on Github.

Answer (score 0):

Design your layout with two panels. Left panel with visibility GONE. And then in onClick method of your button at top-right, make visibility of left panel VISIBLE. You can create a Animation to open left panel smothly.